# Phonegap Android-Application stopped Unexpectedly-E/SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins

I am using phonegap android plugin (childbrowser ) to open a new page using showWebPage(url).However when I go back to the previous page,I always get the "**Application stopped Unexpectedly** FORCE CLOSE" alert...The log from my logcat says:

E/SQLiteDatabase(13575): Failed to open the database. closing it.
E/SQLiteDatabase(13575): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file
E/SQLiteDatabase(13575):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
E/SQLiteDatabase(13575):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:978)
E/SQLiteDatabase(13575):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:951)
E/SQLiteDatabase(13575):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:927)
E/SQLiteDatabase(13575):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1008)
E/SQLiteDatabase(13575):    at com.phonegap.Storage.openDatabase(Storage.java:153)
E/SQLiteDatabase(13575):    at com.phonegap.Storage.execute(Storage.java:61)
E/SQLiteDatabase(13575):    at com.phonegap.api.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:145)
E/SQLiteDatabase(13575):    at com.phonegap.DroidGap$GapClient.onJsPrompt(DroidGap.java:887)
E/SQLiteDatabase(13575):    at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:578)
E/SQLiteDatabase(13575):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/SQLiteDatabase(13575):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
E/SQLiteDatabase(13575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
E/SQLiteDatabase(13575):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/SQLiteDatabase(13575):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
E/SQLiteDatabase(13575):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
E/SQLiteDatabase(13575):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
E/SQLiteDatabase(13575):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
D/AndroidRuntime(13575): Shutting down VM

Not sure why this is happening.Any ideas folks?Thank you

Comment: Does any one have any idea about this..?This comes when I go back from the webview page and try to open my db say window.opendatabase

Comment: Potential lock issue on the database?